# Python regex engine escape bracket within character class

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why in python if we use 2 bracket within character class without escape them if match `[]` but not `]` or `[` :

```
>>> re.search(r'[[]]','[]').group()
'[]'
>>> re.search(r'[[]]','[').group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

But if we escape them it will work as expected :

```
>>> re.search(r'[\[\]]','[').group()
'['
>>> re.search(r'[\[\]]',']').group()
']'
```

Comment: once the regex engine finds `]`, it consider this as a the end of char class. So we have (`[[]` = `[`) + (`]` = `]`) which inturn matches `[]` but fails to match `[` because it expects another `]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, i think that its the reason!

Comment: Note that you can use this trick to define a character class with the two brackets without any escape: `[][]` (it works because empty character class is not allowed and the first closing bracket is seen as a literal character)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yeah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An opening bracket `[` starts a new character class, whose scope ends as soon as it encounters the first closing bracket - `]`.

Now, consider your regex:

```
[[]]
```

The scope of character class started by first `[`, ends at 3rd position. So, the regex is nothing but, `[` (as in character class) followed by `]` (The last character). So, clearly it won't match a `[`.

But, as soon as you escape the first `]`, it loses its behaviour of closing the character class. So, in the below regex:

```
[[\]]
```

the character class gets closed only by the last `]`. So, the regex would match either `[`, or `]`.

Note: There isn't any need to escape `[` inside a character class, as it doesn't have a special behaviour there. It can't start a new character class inside a character class, also, it can't close the existing character class.